# How can I get a custom font weight for the system font, in-between regular and light?

Tags: ios, fonts, custom-keyboard

I'm using the iOS system font (San Francisco for iOS 9+) in my custom keyboard extension.

I've noticed the font shown in the system keyboard has a lighter weight than `UIFontWeightRegular` but it is also bolder than `UIFontWeightLight`.

How can I implement a font in my own keyboard with the same weight that's used in the stock keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

The `systemFontOfSize:weight:` API allows you to specify any weight as a `CGFloat`, and iOS will return the most appropriate font.

For example, instead of `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)` you could do `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17, weight: 0)`. Play with the `weight` value to determine if you can get a font that appears as desired.

Another option could be to try using HTML & CSS with an attributed string. Using `font-weight` you can specify a value between 100 and 900, where 400 is equivalent to the normal font weight.

```
var htmlString = "<p>A</p>"
htmlString += "<style>p{font-family:'-apple-system'; font-size:17px; font-weight:300}</style>"
let htmlData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)!
let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
], documentAttributes: nil)
self.aLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Update: Trying this out, neither solution allows finer control over the font weight. Both will render the text with the closest font for the given weight - Regular or Light but nothing in-between. You may need to resort to custom text drawing if you wish to add a thicker stroke to a thin font. You might investigate drawing via [`NSAttributedString`'s drawing API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW29). You may be able to apply a custom stroke width via `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName`. I have not tried this myself but it was a thought that might be worth investigating.

Comment: I've tried to use `CGFloat` , and `UIFontWeightLight` of SF font is `-0.4` . And `UIFontWeightRegular` is `0` I set it at `-0.2` to get middle weight between light and regular, but it automatically converts to light or regular in case of the number is close to which one.

Comment: You can test, i can't get exactly weight of the stock keyboard font.

Comment: You might try using CSS @TomSawyer, see updated answer

Comment: I dont think this i the good method to fix the font weight. I've test to apply it to UIButton, and get it really slow. Doesnt show any text.

Comment: If you're using `UIButton`, you'll need to use the `setAttributedTitle:forState:` API.

Comment: I wondering if i use attributedText, what is about `setTitle` method? and position of the text in the `UIButton` can i adjust it?

Comment: I do, but i cant update / change text by use `setAttributedTitle` ?